# Use JQuery to check if a String exists in an index of an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I am doing the following to check if a `String` exists in an array:

```
  $('#finance').click(function(){ // Show Finance & OD
                console.log('Finance jobs');
                for(i = 0; i < jobs.length; i ++){
                    if(jobs[i].department === "Finance & OD"){
                        console.log(jobs[i]);
                    }
                }
            });
```

However, I'd like to just check if a `sub string` exists and for it to not be case sensitive. So I tried this but It did not work:

```
$('#finance').click(function(){ // Show Finance & OD
                    console.log('Finance jobs');
                    for(i = 0; i < jobs.length; i ++){
                        if(jobs[i].department.toLowerCase().indexOf("Finance & OD") >= 0){
                            console.log(jobs[i]);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I got this error in the console window: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined**

I'm wondering how I could fix my code so that rather checking for the entire string, I would check for part of the String say "Finance" for example and that it would not be case sensitive.

Comment: can you show what does 'jobs' variable contain..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
$('#finance').click(function(){ // Show Finance & OD
                    console.log('Finance jobs');
                    for(i = 0; i < jobs.length; i ++){
                        if(jobs[i].department != 'undefined' && jobs[i].department.toLowerCase().indexOf("Finance & OD") >= 0){
                            console.log(jobs[i]);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I think the problem is that you loop through some "undefineds" and therefor get an uncatched exception.

Answer (score 1):

This is you can check for particular word and also not case-sensitive:

```
var jobs = ["Finance & OD", "texT"];
for( var i in jobs ) {

    var regex = new RegExp( "Finance", "i" );
    if( jobs[i].match( regex ) ) {
        console.log(jobs[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for undefined. Try this:

```
if(jobs[i].department != "undefined" && jobs[i].department.toLowerCase().indexOf("Finance & OD") >= 0){
     console.log(jobs[i]);
}
```